# Console Wait for KeyPress but not read any key into console buffer?

Tags: c#

I'm confused about the console in C#... basically I have been trying to print out formatted text into the console and have found that anytime I use ReadKey it actually reads that char into the console and this puts my printOuts all out of wack.

This is a dumbed down example but I think it illiterates the point without all superfluous confusing code.

```
        Console.ReadKey(); // Wait for user input before print
        for (int i = 0; i<2000; i++)
        {
            Console.Write('*');
        }
        Console.ReadKey(); // pause console so it dose exit immediately
```

This code waits for a ReadKey and ReadKey stops everything until the code is read. Then it simply prints a * a massive amount of times.

The problem with this code, is that when you press anyKey to "pass the pause".. the console actually reads that key. So if you press a space, the first * is one space forward. If you press ESC you actually get a strange character on screen I do not know the name of.

[image: Example as an Image]
Ok.. so that is all annoying! Then I tried to use KeyAvailable.. which returns true is a key is not pressed. This means you can use a while loop of some time to know if a key is pressed without actually using ReadKey(). You can even use code to only stop the loop when a certain key is pressed. if you like.

```
        do
        { // do nothing in here.. just loop so it acts like a pause

        } while (!Console.KeyAvailable);

        for (int i = 0; i<2000; i++)
        {
            Console.Write('*');
        }
        Console.ReadKey(); // pause console so it dose exit immediately
```

The problem here is that while this works. The Console has already processed some kind of input form the user.. even though it has done nothing with it, but break that loop.

Meaning at the next ReadKey() that is supposed to pause again so the window stays on screen.. there has already BEEN a key pressed.. and that key is then applied to the ReadKey().... so the app instantly closed.

**TL;DR**

1. How can I pause the console and wait for user input but have no feedback into the console of anytime, apart from continuing to execute some code. So no printing to screen, and no actual reading of inputs.
2. Is it possible to lock out all input into the console until you specifically allow it? At the mo if you load a console and mash the keyboard, those keystrokes are still entering the buffer.. how can you stop or clear that before executing some code?

Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation for the available Console.ReadKey method overloads. You might be positively surprised: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_ ;-) With regard to point 2: Before asking for a key press, check/read all possible buffered key presses until none is left. Then ask for a key press again ;-)

Comment: "check/read all possible buffered key presses until none is left. " - how do you do that?

Comment: KeyAvailable and ReadKey. You already use both of them in your code, so you should know what each of them does. Now you only need to combine them to read any possible key available in the key buffer until the key buffer is empty...

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by this. Like I can put a 2nd readkey at the end of all the code and it will not esc now.. as the key pressed to break the while loop feeds into that readkey.. but "emptying the possible key presses" ... I do not get how that would be done.

Comment: Use the `ReadKey(bool)` overload that elgonzo linked in his first comment.

Comment: the ReadKey(true) dosn't stop the keypress continuing onto the 2nd readKey .

Comment: Sorry, thought you meant that you didn't want a key to output anything to the console. I have a little trouble understanding what purpose this is supposed to fulfill, but if you want to empty the key buffer just call `ReadKey` whenever `KeyAvailable` is true.

Comment: If you want to halt execution at a certain point I recommend looking into a [`ManualResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent). Then to empty the key buffer before the rest of your code executes, simply loop: `while (Console.KeyAvailable) { Console.ReadKey(); }`.

Comment: @vincent - oh.. that code is so obvious! I feel like a doofus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Visual Vincent and Elgonzo I have found / been given a solution for this. As they didn't respond with a "post" I couldn't mark anything as solved... so I am making this post to compile their points into a solved post for this question.

You can find the .Net Api stuff for Console.ReadKey(booleens)<[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_)>

Basically this is saying that a true/false parameter will stop the visual feedback into the console.

```
Console.ReadKey(true)
```

Stops the read key being echoed into the console window. This Fixes "**Question 1**"

The other "**Question 2**" can be solved by "clearing the input command buffer"... I am not 100% sure those terms are correct.. but there is a way to quickly make sure any unwanted are inputs are "used" so they do not interfere in actual user input getting when you want it.

```
while (Console.KeyAvailable) { Console.ReadKey(true); }
```

This is a simple while loop that loops until all the buffered keys are cleared by calling ReadKey() and doing nothing with the input.

There was also talk of [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent) but I have yet to look into this.

Thanks for all the help!